# Cannot inject object provided in AppModule to Activity in a dynamic feature module with Dagger2

Tags: android, dagger-2, dynamic-feature-module

With the set up below i'm not be able to inject a Singleton object to a  Activity inside a dynamic feature module. I can inject to a subComponent, MainActivity, but not to an Activity that's in dynamic feature module.

```
@Component(modules = [AppModule::class])
interface AppComponent {

    fun inject(application: Application)

    @Component.Factory
    interface Factory {
        fun create(@BindsInstance application: Application): AppComponent
    }

    // Types that can be retrieved from the graph
    fun mainActivityComponentFactory(): MainActivitySubComponent.Factory
}
```

My AppModule

```
@Module(includes = [AppProviderModule::class])
abstract class AppModule {

    @Binds
    abstract fun bindContext(application: Application): Context
}

@Module
object AppProviderModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideSharedPreferences(application: Application): SharedPreferences {
        return application.getSharedPreferences("PrefName", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    }
}
```

Dynamic Feature Module GalleryComponent

```
@GalleryScope
@Component(
        dependencies = [AppComponent::class],
        modules = [GalleryModule::class])
interface GalleryComponent {
    fun inject(galleryActivity: GalleryActivity)
}
```

And MyApplication

```
open class MyApplication : Application() {

    // Instance of the AppComponent that will be used by all the Activities in the project
    val appComponent: AppComponent by lazy {
        initializeComponent()
    }

    open fun initializeComponent(): AppComponent {
        // Creates an instance of AppComponent using its Factory constructor
        // We pass the applicationContext that will be used as Application
        return DaggerAppComponent.factory().create(this).apply {
            inject(this@MyApplication)
        }
    }
}
```

Activity in dynamic feature module, when only inject `GalleryViewer` and `DummyDependency` is injected from `GalleryModule` it works fine

```
class GalleryActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences

    @Inject
    lateinit var galleryViewer: GalleryViewer

    @Inject
    lateinit var dummyDependency: DummyDependency

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        DaggerGalleryComponent.builder()
                .appComponent((application as MyApplication).appComponent)
                .build()
                .inject(this)

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_gallery)
}
```

When i try to inject SharedPreferences or any dependency that does not depend on any arguments like context or application from `AppModule` i get error

```
error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] android.content.SharedPreferences cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
```

Comment: I think you need to expose fun provideSharedPreferences(): SharedPreferences inside AppComponent

Comment: @ErikJhordanRey it's already included to AppComponent, if you wish to have both abstract and static methods inside a module that's how you do it. I also figured out how to solve it.

Comment: I has same issue. What is the solution?

Comment: @PhongBM i added solution. You can check it out. I used it in sample apps, it works out.

Comment: I don't want provide SharedPreferences like your demo. I have many objects provided in AppModule.
Do you have another solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error here is not including **provision method** for dependencies in `AppComponent` and not building dynamic feature component properly.

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [AppModule::class])
interface AppComponent {

    /**
     *  This method is required to get this object from a class that uses this component
     * as dependent component
     */
    fun provideSharedPreferences(): SharedPreferences

    fun inject(application: Application)

    @Component.Factory
    interface Factory {
        fun create(@BindsInstance application: Application): AppComponent
    }

    // Types that can be retrieved from the graph
    fun mainActivityComponentFactory(): MainActivitySubComponent.Factory
}
```

In dynamic feature

```
@GalleryScope
@Component(
        dependencies = [AppComponent::class],
        modules = [GalleryModule::class])
interface GalleryComponent {

    fun inject(galleryActivity: GalleryActivity)

    // Alternative1 With Builder
    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {

        fun build(): GalleryComponent

        @BindsInstance
        fun application(application: Application): Builder
        fun galleryModule(module: GalleryModule): Builder

        fun appComponent(appComponent: AppComponent): Builder

    }

    // Alternative2 With Factory
    @Component.Factory
    interface Factory {

        fun create(appComponent: AppComponent,
                   galleryModule: GalleryModule,
                   @BindsInstance application: Application): GalleryComponent


    }
}
```

You must either use `Builder` or `Factory`, with hilt none of this might be necessary in the future, however it does not support dynamic feature yet, i rather factory pattern since they deprecated Builder pattern.

inside Activity `onCreate` initialize injection

```
private fun initInjections() {

    // Alternative1 With Builder
    DaggerGalleryComponent.builder()
            .appComponent((application as MyApplication).appComponent)
            .application(application)
            .galleryModule(GalleryModule())
            .build()
            .inject(this)

    // Alternative2 With Factory
    DaggerGalleryComponent
            .factory()
            .create((application as MyApplication).appComponent, GalleryModule(), application)
            .inject(this)

}
```

You should choose the same pattern used inside feature component.